# Sync file under use

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I Want use autosync function in a database manager program. The autosync automaticaly upload the database file to cloud if it was changed.

*My problem is, the database always using the database file, and the upload method can't access to the file.*

The code:

File name is main.db

using in insert, and BackgroundUploadAsync methods

```
  public static async void InsertToDatabase(object data)
        {

            SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("Main.db");
            await conn.InsertAsync(data);//i cant close the file in async methode
        }

  public async static void AutoSync()
{
....

if (file != null)
                    {

                        var progressHandler = new Progress<LiveOperationProgress>(
                            (progress) => { /*pr.Value = progress.ProgressPercentage;*/ });
                        SettingsFlyout1.ctsUpload = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource();
                        LiveConnectClient liveClient = new LiveConnectClient(app.Session);

                        await liveClient.BackgroundUploadAsync(result, file.Name, file, OverwriteOption.Overwrite, SettingsFlyout1.ctsUpload.Token, progressHandler);
                    }
}


private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

    InsertToDatabase(adat);
    AutoSync();//file not found exception,

    }
```

**Thanx for Help or any suggestons !**

Answer (score 0):

This may not be ideal space-wise, but you could create two database files. One `in-use`, and one `at-rest`.

After each write (or set of writes) copy the `in-use` over the `at-rest` before writing any more entries to the DB. You may need to disconnect, then reconnect after copying. This should be a pretty quick operation though (much faster than uploading it).

Then, when you need to upload, stream from the `at-rest` version.

You'll need locks on read/write of the `at-rest`, but at least you can read/write to the `in-use` without being bounded by the internet connection.